# Multi-byte character set is not found in VS2015 VC++ Redistributables

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc, com, windows-10

I have created a simple plane MFC application using VS 2015 and if i try to run the exe in another windows 10 machine where VC++ 2015 redistributables are present, then exe is not getting launch.

If i change it to Unicode then it works fine in another machine where VC++ 2015 redistributables are present, its failing specific MBCS.

in the Event viewer i noticed below error,

```
"Application popup: MFCApplication2.exe - System Error : The code execution cannot proceed because mfc140.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem."
```

i checked the mfc140.dll its present in system 32 folder, also i placed the same dll at the exe level and run. again new error noticed in event viewer like

```
Application popup: MFCApplication2.exe - Application Error : The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b). Click OK to close the application.
```

For testing purpose, i made the application as static linkage, in that case its working fine in another machine, but for dynamic linkage the exe is not launching in another machine.

Here are the list of VC++ Redistributes present in the windows 10 machine.

[image]

How we can fix the issue?

Edit,
Here i found MBCS installer for 2013 (http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9832071). But if i run i'm seeing below error, why we require VS for running MBCS i'm not understanding.

[image]

thanks

Comment: MFC's MBCS DLL (I FEEL LIKE I'M SHOUTING) is a separate download.http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9832071 (warning: that's a direct download link).

Comment: But, is this comptabile with windows 10 and built for VS 2015

Comment: Unless I copied the wrong thing, it's intended for VS 2015, yes. The result should be compatible with Windows 10, but I haven't tested that personally.

Comment: Hi, in the plane machine if i install, its throwing error saying it requires MS Visual studio. Moreover setup says its for VS 2013. Kindly help

Comment: Oops--I must have found the wrong link. I'll look a bit more (but I'll only be doing pretty much the same things you can about as easily as I can).

Comment: Hi, i have updated the question, please have look, as per the installer the above error is appearing. thanks for the support. please have look

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/mfc-mbcs-dll-add-on